# Countably Compact vs Compact vs Finite Intersection Property

Tags: general-topology, compactness

There is this exercise: Show that countable compactness is equivalent to the following condition.  If ${C_n}$ is a countable collection of closed sets in S satisfying the finite intersection hypothesis, then $\bigcap_{i=1}^\infty C_i$ is nonempty.

Definitions:

- A Space S is countably compact if every infinite subset of S has a limit point in S.
- A space S has the finite intersection property provided that if ${C_\alpha}$ is any collection of closed sets such that any finite number of them has a nonempty intersection, then the total intersection $\bigcap_\alpha C_\alpha$ is non-empty
- A family of closed sets, in any space, such that any finite number of them has a nonempty intersection, will be said to satisfy the finite intersection hypothesis.

Now there is also a related theorem in the book: Compactness is equivalent to the finite intersection property.

Sounds to me countable compactness and compactness are pretty much the same.

I am not asking for a solution to the exercise.  My question is this:

What is the difference between Compactness and Countable Compactness in terms of closed Collections?  Both things sound to me like this: Given a collection of closed sets, when a finite number of them has a nonempty intersection, all of them have a nonempty intersection.

BTW: the definitions, the theorems and the exercise are from Topology by Hocking/Young.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference is that if $X$ is compact, **every** collection of closed sets with the finite intersection property has a non-empty intersection; if $x$ is only countably compact, this is guaranteed only for **countable** collections of closed sets with the finite intersection property. In a countably compact space that is not compact, there will be some **uncountable** collection of closed sets that has the finite intersection property but also has empty intersection.

An example is the space $\omega_1$ of countable ordinals with the order topology. For each $\xi<\omega_1$ let $F_\xi=\{\alpha<\omega_1:\xi\le\alpha\}=[\xi,\omega_1)$, and let $\mathscr{F}=\{F_\xi:\xi<\omega_1\}$. $\mathscr{F}$ is a nested family: if $\xi<\eta<\omega_1$, then $F_\xi\supsetneqq F_\eta$. Thus, it certainly has the finite intersection property: if $\{F_{\xi_0},F_{\xi_1},\dots,F_{\xi_n}\}$ is any finite subcollection of $\mathscr{F}$, and $\xi_0<\xi_1<\ldots<\xi_n$, then $F_{\xi_0}\cap F_{\xi_1}\cap\ldots\cap F_{\xi_n}=F_{\xi_n}\ne\varnothing$. But $\bigcap\mathscr{F}=\varnothing$, because for each $\xi<\omega_1$ we have $\xi\notin F_{\xi+1}$. This space is a standard example of a countably compact space that it not compact.

**Added:** Note that neither of them says:

> Given a collection of closed sets, when a finite number of them has a nonempty intersection, all of them have a nonempty intersection.

The finite intersection property is not that **some** finite number of the sets has non-empty intersection: it says that **every** finite subfamily has non-empty intersection. Consider, for instance, the sets $\{0,1\},\{1,2\}$, and $\{0,2\}$: every two of them have non-empty intersection, but the intersection of all three is empty. This little collection of sets does not have the finite intersection property.

Here is perhaps a better way to think of these results. In a compact space, if you have a collection $\mathscr{C}$ of closed sets whose intersection $\bigcap\mathscr{C}$ is empty, then some finite subcollection of $\mathscr{C}$ already has empty intersection: there is some positive integer $n$, and there are some $C_1,\dots,C_n\in\mathscr{C}$ such that $C_1\cap\ldots\cap C_n=\varnothing$. In a countably compact space something similar but weaker is true: if you have a **countable** collection $\mathscr{C}$ of closed sets whose intersection $\bigcap\mathscr{C}$ is empty, then some finite subcollection of $\mathscr{C}$ already has empty intersection. In a countably compact space you can’t in general say anything about uncountable collections of closed sets with empty intersection.

Comment: Thanks for this great explanation, Brian. So it's really all about the attribute "countable"... Ironically I encountered the standard example some pages before in an exercise; there it was in the context of subbases though.