# Compact vs Countably Compact Spaces (Example of the space of countable ordinals)

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I am having trouble understanding why the space of countable ordinals with the order topology is countably compact but not compact.

I know that one of the key diferences between these two concepts is that in compact spaces $\textbf{every}$ centered collection of closed sets has a non empty intersection, while in a countably compact space, only $\textbf{countable}$ centered collections of closed sets have a non empty intersection.

So in order to prove that the space of countable ordinals is countably compact and not compact, I need to show that countable centered collections of closed sets have a nonempty intersection, and at least find one uncountable centered collection of closed sets with an empty intersection.

My question is, how can there even be an uncountable collection of sets in the space of countable ordinals? Aren´t they all countable? And since collections are merely subsets of the whole space, how can we construct an $\textit{uncountable}$ collection of countable ordinals?

Comment: There uncountably many (to be precise $\aleph_1$ many) distinct countable ordinals

Comment: Moreover, even the space $\omega$ of *finite* ordinals has uncountably many subsets.

Comment: Thanks for the coments. This and your reply @BrianM.Scott to this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160876/countably-compact-vs-compact-vs-finite-intersection-property?rq=1) helped a lot!

Comment: @MathiasBarreto: Glad it helped.